# Use generate_series to populate list of months for a given year in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, generate-series

I have the following query that generates list of months for given year when input is date (`2014-01-01`):

```
SELECT to_char(dd, 'Month') 
FROM generate_series(CAST('2014-01-01' AS DATE), date_trunc('month', now()), '1 month') as dd;

  to_char  
-----------
 January  
 February 
(2 rows)
```

Now, instead of `2014-01-01` I need to pass only `2014` and get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct to_char(dd, 'Month') FROM generate_series(to_date('2013', 'YYYY') , date_trunc('month', now()), '1 month') as dd;
```

Comment: thanks but the o/p has the additional 2 values of January and February
each

Comment: @AmitSharad Sorry, i did not understand what you just said: `thanks but the o/p has the additional 2 values of January and February each`

Comment: If you input year as 2013 , it will return additional January ad February , please verify

Comment: @AmitSharad So you want to get distinct values of month ? Please update your question to be more specific.

Comment: @Houri 
Yes you're correct the distinct Month values , anyways I will accept your answer. Thank you for your comments and time on this :)

Comment: @AmitSharad I just updated my answer to get a distinct values of months

Answer (score 2):

You can apped `-01-01` to year input:

```
SELECT 
  to_char(dd, 'Month') 
FROM 
  generate_series(
      ('2013' || '-01-01')::date, 
      ('2013' || '-01-01')::date + interval '1 year' - interval '1 day', 
      '1 month') as dd;
```

Comment: thanks but the o/p has the additional 2 values of January and February
each

Comment: @AmitSharad Please be more specific. My query returns two rows, you expect different number of rows?

Comment: If you input year as 2013 , it will return additional January ad February , please verify

Comment: @AmitSharad Fixed to adjust for different year.